# Логирование во фронтенд разработке

Tags: reactjs, redux

Искал но так и не нашел практики логирования фронтенда. Логи судя по всему должны уходить в сеть. Сама эта мысль, какая то сырая - мы будем трафик пользователя тратить на ненужные ему наши логи - так себе идея. Как логировать фронтенд? Использую модненькие реакты и редаксы

Comment: Для начала определитесь, зачем вам его вообще логировать?

Comment: Логи нужны для дебага. Может быть можно получать стек трейс. Я же не знаю какие практики на фронте, поэтому и спросил

Comment: Ну вот когда ошибка случится, тогда стек трэйс себе и отправляйте. Пока ошибок нет, трафик тратиться, очевидно, не будет